# opencl clGetDeviceID error (17334360 devices)

Tags: opencl, gpu

Im trying to run opencl hallo world on my gt610 gpu
(gpu-z raports this supports OpenCl 1.1)

when i am running

```
    static  cl_device_id device_id[10] = {0};
    static cl_uint num_devices__ = 20;
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs_( platform_id[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 10, device_id, &num_devices__ );
    if(ret == CL_SUCCESS) printf("get device id success , devices %d ", num_devices__) ;
```

it returns succes, but gives the num_devices of 17334360, otherwise it seem to work
(if i give CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR this returns CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) also platform_id seem to be ok ...

I got no heel clue what it can be :C
could someone help?

(I am using the opencl.dll which i found in windows/system32 (1.0)
and load dynamically to that (using opencl 1.1 header taken from khronos page
- i got modem connection and cannot download the sdk, need to load
this way - but it seem to work good api is workink ok)

EDIT

i use this trash code (its experimental trying to run this)

```
    SetupDllFunctions();

    int ret;
    static cl_platform_id platform_id[10] = {0};
    int platforms_found = 0;
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs_(10, platform_id, &platforms_found);
    if(ret == CL_SUCCESS ) printf("clGetPlatformIDs success") ;
    printf(" %d platforms found",platforms_found ) ;
    static char profile[1000];
    size_t size;
    clGetPlatformInfo_(platform_id[0], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, NULL, profile, &size);
    clGetPlatformInfo_(platform_id[0], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, size, profile, NULL);
    printf(" %s ", profile);
    static  cl_device_id device_id[10] = {0};
    static cl_uint num_devices__ = 20;
    int platformid = platform_id[0];
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs_( platformid, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 10, device_id, &num_devices__ );
    if(ret == CL_SUCCESS) printf("get device id success , devices %d ", num_devices__) ;

    if(ret == CL_INVALID_PLATFORM) printf("CL_INVALID_PLATFORM") ;
    if(ret == CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE ) printf("CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE ") ;
    if(ret == CL_INVALID_VALUE ) printf("CL_INVALID_VALUE ") ;
    if(ret == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND ) printf("CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND ") ;

    cl_context context = clCreateContext_(0, 1, device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    printf("..... ") ;

    if(ret == CL_SUCCESS) printf("context success ") ;
    if(ret ==CL_INVALID_PLATFORM) printf("CL_INVALID_PLATFORM ") ;
    if(ret ==CL_INVALID_VALUE) printf("CL_INVALID_VALUE ") ;
    if(ret ==CL_INVALID_DEVICE) printf("CL_INVALID_DEVICE ") ;
    if(ret ==CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE) printf("CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE ") ;
    if(ret ==CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY) printf("CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY ") ;
```

the output is

clGetPlatformIDs success 1 platforms found OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.2.1 get device id success , devices 17334336 ..... CL_INVALID_DEVICE

the first trouble is 17 mln devices the second invalid device

the underscores i added becouse i grab the functions by get proc adress 
(i am using header when they are defined so i added _ not to conflict)
the opencl.dll is found on my machine in windows system32, still cannot
get the sdk - maybe if some could upload the opencl.dll import lib open.cl.lib and headers so i could use this... but this dynamic linking i think maybe also should work (some calls work, platform string was returned

Comment: How does platform_id[0] get initialized? You didn't include that code. Did you call clGetPlatformIDs? That is required before you call clGetDeviceIDs. If so, was the num_platforms a reasonable value? Why is there an underscore after clGetDeviceIDs? That's not part of the OpenCL API.

Comment: What lib are you using in linking? Or are you just using LoadLibrary? How did you verify that platform_id is ok? Did you query the vendor strings from it? I really recommend that you grab an USB stick and go somewhere to download the SDK. It's going to save you so much trouble.

Comment: If you would like dynamic linking then use CLEW. I would recomend also if you just started with OCL to start with C++ bindings. Probably your problem is how you are defining the funcions in your dynamic loading.

Comment: Also - make sure you're not connecting to your development machine remotely. I had this same exact problem when I was working on a Ray Tracer that used OpenCL. I spent hours on this until I came across a post that informed if you're connecting remotely you can't use OpenCL. Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not connecting remotely and i do not know what i could spoil with defining the functions, i just grab the pointer than cal it ... i will find about clew...

Comment: well i began to suspect what ev it could be... the fetching of fuction names could not check the type arguments safety.. maybe some args i provide had the different size... not sure if this is the thing but maybe